# pyroCMS and codeigniter add-ons

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, pyrocms

Greetings I will just ask very simple question. I'm very new to PyroCMS and I was wondering 
if is possible use same modules, add-ons, widgets and plugins created in Codeigniter for PyroCMS?

Comment: Hmm, aren't they using Laravel :) ?

Comment: I thought that Lavarel is similar framework

Comment: PyroCMS will use Laravel 4 at PyroCMS V.3.0 and now it is on Codeigniter at V.2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

basically yes, but there are some changes you should make in your classes, for example you extend the `public_controller` in Pyrocms modules. take a look at pyrocms docs : http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers